# Add multiple authentication mechanism for different api groups springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-rest

We have an existing spring-boot application that supports basic Authentication with spring-security. this application uses spring templating so it accepts form data as input and saves sessions by doing authentication.

the login page is at `/login` after successful login it redirects to the home page of the website.

in the same spring boot service, we want to start supporting JSON based API which would be used by the Mobile app.
we were thinking of adding login API at `/api/login` which will be served for mobile devices.

is there a way where we can say
for `/login` use default authentication class and for `/api/login` use some other custom class which will read JSON data and will do Authentication.

we also want to use different page for unAuthorized access. as existing one renders custom HTML page. but with API we want to send JSON response with HTTP code.

Answer (score 0):

Not a Java person, but generally speaking this can be done by creating a different controller that would handle the `/api/login` route.

Here's snippet below that might help :
[Source : https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/]

```
package com.example.springboot;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("/api/login")
    public String LoginAPI() {
        // handle your authentication logic here. 
    }

}
```

I would strongly recommend against using the session based authentication. It's simply not designed for modern applications. If the option is open, you can take a upgrade to token based authentication ([jwt.io](https://jwt.io)), that would make your life much much easier.

If you must implement the session based authentication for mobile app as well. here's what you need to do

1. create the session on server
2. set the session key as a part of cookies in the response header
3. store the cookies in your app.
4. Include the cookies in request header in subsequent API calls from mobile app.

Again, not a Java person. Just hoping to help.